# Hive 1.2.1 regex usage

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am using hive 1.2.1 currently in my project.I have below requirement in hive using regex. Can any one help me ..here is my requirement. In one of my existing hive external table one column values are

### Column-1

grade:position

grade:type: first grade

a=first/https://mobile.apps.com/web/wwws/topper/test/summary?c_name=grade_&n

grade:notapplicable

a=first/apps-bin/apps/u/gradeStatus

grade:firstpage

grade:LoginID

grade:Login:password

===========================

The above are my column values in Hive table.I want the output like

position

type/first grade

topper/test/summary

notapplicable

gradeStatus

firstpage

LoginID

Login/password

==================================================

regex_replace also works but Can any one help me on this?

So far i have tried the following

```
select regexp_replace(type_nm,'a=first(\/http(s:|:)|)|^.+?:| - financial carrers|^\w+(//|\/)|(//)|Pgrade\?gradename=|(\..+|)(\/(web|webbased|apps-bin|man‌​ual)((\/wwws|\/apps\/u\/)(\/topper|)|))|\?.+','') AS GRADE_DETAILS from db_admin.yearly_grade
```

Comment: please include code examples of what you have tried

Comment: select regexp_replace(type_nm,'a=first(\/http(s:|:)|)|^.+?:| - financial carrers|^\w+(//|\/)|(//)|Pgrade\?gradename=|(\..+|)(\/(web|webbased|apps-bin|manual)((\/wwws|\/apps\/u\/)(\/topper|)|))|\?.+','')    
AS GRADE_DETAILS 
from db_admin.yearly_grade